# LinkedIn Sign In Bad Redirect invalid redirect_uri

Tags: linkedin-api

Trying to sign in using LinkedIn for a mobile device, but it won't redirect without throwing an error (awesomescreenshot.com/0054zr6hda).

The error page URL is:

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?state=foo=&response_type=code&client_id=foo&redirect_uri=http://local.foo.com:3000/registrations/linkedin

In LinkedIn developer apps, I have added the following SDK domain:

http://local.foo.com/registrations/linkedin

I have played around with other valid SDK variations, but always get the Bad Request error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you try adding redirect URL as `http://local.foo.com:3000/registrations/linkedin` in LinkedIn developer app

Comment: Yes, no change (plus all the other working URLs don't have the port number).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

In the LinkedIn developer app page I was adding the URLs under the JavaScript "Valid SDK Domains" under "JavaScript" rather than "Authorized Redirect URLs" under "Authentication".

Doh!